# ERROR: Removing metadata components from a second-generation managed package is a pilot feature that requires acceptance into a pilot program

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx-cli, 2gp

I am trying to create a new package version using `2GP`.

When I run this command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create ...
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Can’t create package version. Removing metadata components from a second-generation managed package is a pilot feature that requires acceptance into a pilot program.

At the time of posting, the Partner Community support section is broken, so I cannot raise a case.

Based on the error message, it obviously thinks I've deleted something, is there a command I can run to figure out what the deleted metadata is?

Comment: don't you version control your metadata?

Comment: I do. But my git install got corrupt, so there was a 3 month period when I didn't commit any changes... ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The bug has been fixed and the error message now contains the metadata components that you are trying to delete

Original answer:

There is no way to see the root cause of the error without opening a Case

They have created a Known Issue about this -- that is, the error message should identify the metadata you're attempting to delete:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001nTzbQAE

Additionally, in our case, the problem was due to Profiles in package directories OUTSIDE of the package directory that I was trying to package. Apparently the 2GP packaging process pays attention to Profiles in ALL of the directories listed in the `packageDirectories` array in `sfdx-project.json` when computing the metadata payload to send up for packaging. If you delete a Profile from one of these directories, you get the error documented by the OP

Comment: does this require premier support?

Comment: Yes, to get to the root cause of the error above, we had to use Premier Support. However, the bug has been fixed now for about 2 months and you will now get an error message that enumerates the list of components that you're trying to delete when building the package version